# Bourbaki... caveman(?) symbol

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

I don't know if this is the best place to ask this question, but I'm sure many of you are familiar with the Bourbaki "dangerous bend" symbol:
[image]
The idea behind the symbol is to indicate a particularly conceptually challenging part of the text, which could potentially be skipped when reading through for the first time.

Now, my question is: is there an equivalent "caveman" symbol?

I came across this in a set of notes on analysis:
[image]

The symbol appears next to all definitions, I suppose the idea is that when a concept is defined (especially in analysis) we are bound to discover something new (akin to a cave man).

What is this symbol called? Is it commonly used, similarly to Bourbaki? Is there a LaTeX package for it?

Comment: Have you tried tex.se? [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) apparently doesn't know either symbol.

Answer (score 8):

I have not seen the caveman symbol.  Therefore, I conclude it is not commonly used.  Any questions about it should be addressed to the author of those analysis notes.

Even for the Bounbaki "dangerous bend" symbol: if you use it, define it the first time.

Answer (score 2):

This symbol can be found on page 151, Table 417 in Scott Pakin's [Comprehensive $\LaTeX$ symbol list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).
It comes from the phaistos symbols and is obtained by the $\LaTeX$ command $\texttt{\\PHpedestrian}$.

Comment: Well, thanks for making me aware of the Phaistos disk. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaistos_Disc So the symbol itself was used in Crete, 4000 years ago. Of course this does not answer what its intended purpose in those analysis notes might be, for which one should still ask those notes' author.